# How to Compute the Options Text from option value in ko

Tags: knockout.js

Hi i want to get the selected Text from the selected value of the Drop down using ko.

My view is :

```
    <select id="country" data-bind="options: CountriesList ,optionsText: 'CountryName',optionsValue:'CountryId',value:CountryId,optionsCaption: 'Select Country..'"
```

Countrieslist will be like: CountryId=1  CoutnryName="Afghanistan" CountryId=2 CountryName="Albania" ...so on

My model:

```
       var stateModel = {

            StateId: ko.observable(0),
            StateName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }).extend({ pattern: { message: 'Enter only Text', params: '^[a-zA-Z ]*$'} }),
            ShortName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }).extend({ pattern: { message: 'Enter only Text', params: '^[a-zA-Z ]*$'} }),
            IsActive: ko.observable(true),
            CountryId: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
            CountriesList: ko.observableArray([]),
            CountryName: ko.computed(function () {
                return $("#country CountryId[value=111]").text();

            })

        };
```

I am trying to compute Country Name from ko.computed... I don't know is that correct way or not..Please help me somebody...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CountryName: function()
     {
     var country = this.CountriesList().filter(function(i)
         {
         return i.CountryId == stateModel.CountryId();
         });

     return country[0].CountryName;
     }
```